# Regex replace hyphens in text excluding urls, tags and mails

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace hyphens in text to non-breaking hyphens, but I need to exlude all URLs, emails and tags. Here is some text I am trying to edit:

> Some text with a link but also plain URL like
> http://another-domain.com and an e-mail info@some-domain.com and
> e-shop and some relative URL like /test-url/on-this-website.

and I came up with this regex: `(^|\s+)[^@|^\/]+(\s+|$)`

But it cannot be used for `preg_replace`, it doesn't match hyphens, but whole text that contains dashes.

Result should be:

```
Some text with a <a href="https://some-domain.com/section-name" class="some-class">link</a> but also plain URL like http://another-domain.com and an e&#8209;mail info@some-domain.com and e&#8209;shop and some relative URL like /test-url/on-this-website.
```

Have anyone been doing something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few issues with your regex...

- You can't use `|` as an OR operator in your character class
- Your regex is greedy
- You can't use multiple `not` operators in a character class
- You don't need to have more than one space matched at the start and end
- Your character class swallows spaces

---

It seems to me that you're over thinking it; you could rephrase your task to: *"replace hyphens in words"*

```
(\s\w+)-(\w+\s)
(\s\w+)            : Capture group matching a white space and then 1 or more of the characters [a-zA-Z0-9_]
        -          : Match a hyphen
         (\w+\s)   : Capture group matching a white space and then 1 or more of the characters [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

However, you can also use your more wide ranging character class like:

```
(\s[^@\/\s]+)-([^@\/\s]+\s)
(\s[^@\/\s]+)                : Capture group matching a space followed by 1 or more characters which aren't  @, /, or a space
             -               : Matches a hyphen
              ([^@\/\s]+\s)  : Capture group matching a space followed by 1 or more characters which aren't  @, /, or a space

$string = "Some text with a link but also plain URL like http://another-domain.com and an e-mail info@some-domain.com and e-shop and some relative URL like /test-url/on-this-website.";

echo preg_replace("/(\s\w+)-(\w+\s)/", "$1&#8209;$2", $string);

echo preg_replace("/(\s[^@\/\s]+)-([^@\/\s]+\s)/", "$1&#8209;$2", $string);
```

Note: You may need to change the starting and closing space to include the start/end of a the string.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I couldn't find proper group regex that would met all conditions. This is exactly what I needed!